# Registering a SecurityTokenReceived Event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

Recently I have started using claim-based authentication on an existing web application. Everything works well, but to better handle expiration of the SessionSecurity tokens, I want to employ sliding expiration.

However, I'm having trouble to register the event handler for the SecurityTokenReceived event.

My handler method is defined like so in the Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

But when register this handler method in the Application_Start of the same file like so:

```
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SecurityTokenReceived += SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived;
```

Visual Studio responds that there exist no overloads for SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived that matches delegate System.EventHandler.

I have the following setting in the  section of the web.config:

```
<securityTokenHandlers>
    <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="0:02" />
    </add>
  </securityTokenHandlers>
```

I have read some of the available documentation on MSDN but I cannot see why the event handler is not accepted. Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Danila Polevshikov's answer, I noticed my mistake. The solution is as follow:

In the Application_Start method, the event handler should have been:

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SessionSecurityTokenReceived += SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived;
```

I need to have the SessionSecurityTokenReceivedArgs argument because I need to re-issue a cookie.

Answer (score 3):

FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SecurityTokenReceived expects method with **SecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs** instead of SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs (as my VS says). Try to change your code to:

```
protected void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thanks Danila, you pointed out the mistake I made. I have answered my own question, but voted your answer up as it helped me too